# What is version of HDMI in Acer Aspire V Nitro VN7-592G ? 1.4 or 2.0?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, acer-aspire

The question is for owners because I cannot find on official specs page what is version of HDMI in this laptop. It's important for me because I'd like to connect 4K monitor at 60Hz which is supported only by HDMI 2.0. HDMI 1.4 supports 4K only at 30Hz...

So the question is: Actually What is version of HDMI in Acer Aspire V Nitro VN7-592G?

Many thanks everyone for replies!

Comment: That model has the nvidia GeForce GTX 960M graphics which supports 4K but does not specify if it is 2.0  http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-960m/features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [a high-reputation member on the Acer Community forums](http://community.acer.com/t5/V-and-VN-Series-Laptops/What-is-the-version-of-HDMI-in-Acer-Aspire-V-Nitro-VN7-592G-1-4/td-p/415361), it has HDMI 1.4a:

> [vasilysudakov:] What is the version of HDMI in Acer Aspire V Nitro VN7-592G ? 1.4 or 2.0?
>
> [Ironfly:] HDMI 1.4a

Therefore only 30Hz mode is supported. Alternatively you can connect a 4K display at 60Hz via [DisplayPort using USB 3.1 Type C](https://www.displayport.org/displayport-over-usb-c/).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I fixed the DP link. Also, here's the missing citation from Acer that *their* USB-C port supports DisplayPort: [USB-C Specifications for Acer Aspire VN7-592G Black Edition](https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45749/~/usb-c-specifications-for-acer-aspire-vn7-592g-black-edition)